# Firebase Invalid Project Id when trying to recover lost group notification key

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

While testing my server-side php functions to create device groups i lost track of the `notification key` returned as a result of successfully creating a device group.

As described in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/ytovugx8XNs i tried

```
curl -v  -H Content-Type:application/json -H Authorization:key=<your api key> 
-H project_id:<your project id> 
https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification?notification_key_name=testgroup
```

where the project id is the one found in firebase console, the same shown in the url and the very same present even in my `google-services.json`

As a result i get

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request  Content-Type: application/json;
>   charset=UTF-8  Date: Tue, 18 Apr 2017 08:21:30 GMT  Expires: Tue, 18
>   Apr 2017 08:21:30 GMT  Cache-Control: private, max-age=0 
>   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN 
>   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block  Server: GSE  Alt-Svc: quic=":443";
>   ma=2592000; v="37,36,35"  Accept-Ranges: none  Vary: Accept-Encoding 
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   * Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
>   * Connection #0 to host android.googleapis.com left intact {"error":"INVALID_PROJECT_ID"}

I can't find a way out of this, since after losing a notification key the only way to recover it is with that command (afaik) . Please help.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean you're using the `project-id` (visible in the *google-services.json*)?

Comment: yes, which is the same present in firebase console's url and the same in console>Settings as well

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Project ID that should be used for FCM is the *Sender ID*. This value can be seen in the Firebase Console > Settings > **Cloud Messaging** Tab.

If you refer to the *google-services.json* file, the value for `project_number` should be the one you use (same value as seen from the Firebase Console). It's a *numerical-only* value.

Comment: Ah ! thanks you were right! I just thought that project_id would have been...well, the project id. Unfortunately, Now i get `{"error":"notification_key not found"}` but if i try to create a group with the same `notification_key_name` parameter, specified in the url, i get `notification_key already exists` !

Comment: You're welcome. For your follow up, have you tried sending the request directly using Postman or cURL and see if it's the same scenario? Are you positive that the `notification_key_name` you're using in both request are identical too? Because if it is, then that's an unexpected behavior already.

Comment: With cURL everything works ! i guess i have some errors in my APIs. Thank you for everything !